# Send multiple variables through render with Express

Tags: node.js, variables, express

Maybe a stupid question but, is it possible to send multiple variables through `res.render()` in Express ?

Because, when I do

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express', name: 'Arnaud' });
```

I've all this pretty error telling me `name` is not defined.

[image]

In this view

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Salut #{name}
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: That should work just fine. Your error have to lie somewhere else.

Comment: Weird think is it's a stock Express project, I just had the variable to the view (question edited with the view)...

Comment: I made a test case http://runnable.com/UWgFzMufwudHAALV but I just spotted your issue: #{title} (which is in layout.jade) is not defined.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Weird thing is weird : I regenerated a new Express project and everything is fine...

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 5):

In route:

```
res.render("index", { data: { title: "Express", name: "Arnaud" } })
```

In view:

```
<%= data.title %>
<%= data.name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem for a long time and found a workaround: to pass a variable you just should do

```
res.locals.title = "Express";
res.locals.name = "Arnaud"
res.render("index");
```

The both variables Express and Arnaud will be given to the EJS context